# Is every submodule contained in a maximal submodule (assuming there are two max. sub.)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let a module $M$ has exactly 2 maximal submodules say $M_1$ and $M_2$. Then is it true to say that ''every proper submodule of $M$  is contained in $M_1$ or $M_2$?''

Comment: Try $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I'm not sure that $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Q $ has exactly 2 maximal sub groups.

Comment: Perhaps then, you could tell us a third.

Comment: OK. I andrstand  the $\Bbb Z$-module $\Bbb Z /6 \Bbb Z×\Bbb Q$ has exactly 2 maximal submodules say $3\Bbb Z/6 \Bbb Z×\Bbb Q$ and $2\Bbb Z /6\Bbb Z×\Bbb Q$, But the submodule $ \Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z×<1/2> $ does not contain in any one.